# How do I calculate onchange with keyup

Tags: jquery

I have 3 input. Package - Total - Price

How do I make the price will change too when the package is changed.

```js
$('#the_total').keyup(function () {
    var the_total = $("#the_total").val();
    var get_package = $("#package").val();
    if (get_package == 'Package A') {
        var total = the_total * 100;
    } else {
        var total = the_total * 200;
    }
    $("#price").val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="package">
    <option value="Package A">Package A</option>
    <option value="Package B">Package B</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="the_total" name="total">
<input type="text" id="price" name="price">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the `keyup` and `change` to both elements using `on`.

```js
$('#the_total, #package').on('change keyup', function() {
  var the_total = $("#the_total").val();
  var get_package = $("#package").val();
  if (get_package == 'Package A') {
    var total = the_total * 100;
  } else {
    var total = the_total * 200;
  }
  $("#price").val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="package">
  <option value="Package A">Package A</option>
  <option value="Package B">Package B</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="the_total" name="total">
<input type="text" id="price" name="price">
```

Answer (score 2):

Trigger the `keyup` on change event.

```js
$('#the_total').keyup(function() {
  var the_total = $("#the_total").val();
  var get_package = $("#package").val();
  if (get_package == 'Package A') {
    var total = the_total * 100;
  } else {
    var total = the_total * 200;
  }
  $("#price").val(total);
});

$('#package').change(function() { // on change
  $('#the_total').keyup(); // trigger this
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="package">
  <option value="Package A">Package A</option>
  <option value="Package B">Package B</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="the_total" name="total">
<input type="text" id="price" name="price">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#the_total').keyup(function() {
       loadPrice();
  });
  $('#package').change(function(){
      loadPrice();
  })
  function loadPrice() {
    var the_total = $("#the_total").val();
    var get_package = $("#package").val();
    if (get_package == 'Package A') {
      var total = the_total * 100;
    } else {
      var total = the_total * 200;
    }
    $("#price").val(total);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
$(function(){
  function doTotal(){
      var the_total = $("#the_total").val();
      var get_package = $("#package").val();
      var total = 0;
      get_package == 'Package A'?total = the_total * 100:total = the_total * 200;
      $("#price").val(total);
  }
  $('#the_total').keyup(function() {
    doTotal();
  });

  $('#package').change(function(){
    doTotal();
  });
});
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tth4x2o9/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use this js -- With few validations

```
$(function() {

    function theChange () {
        var the_total = $("#the_total").val();
        var get_package = $("#package").val();

        if (get_package == 'Package A') {
            var total = the_total * 100;
        } else {
            var total = the_total * 200;
        }

        $("#price").val(total); 
    }

    $('#the_total').keyup(function() { theChange(); });
    $("#package").change(function () { theChange(); });
});
```